# What's wrong my code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string flipwords(string str) {

    string rword = "";
    vector<string> wrd;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        wrd.push_back(str.substr(i,1));
    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    for (int = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        rword += str[i];
    return rword;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    string rword = flipwords(word);

    if (word == rword ) {
        cout << "It's a palindrome.";

    } else {
        cout << "Not a palindrome.";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

When ever I try to run this code it doesn't work at all and I've copied it exactly from a tutorial by InfiniteSkills the code works on the video but on my PC it doesn't !

the compiler gives me the following errors:

```
F:\apsat\Vectors Project\main.cpp|13|error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token|
F:\apsat\Vectors Project\main.cpp|13|error: expected ';' before '=' token|
F:\apsat\Vectors Project\main.cpp|13|error: expected primary-expression before '=' token|
F:\apsat\Vectors Project\main.cpp|13|error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]|
```

I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 with MinGW if that helps.

Comment: `for (int = 0` <-- looks like a missing `i`

Comment: Mindlessly copying code from an online source is usually not a great idea

Comment: Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: It was a video By the way! Mr Tim :)

Comment: Thanks Mr Matt :)
Thanks Mr asawyer :)

Answer (score 5):

This line right here:

`for (int = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)`

should be:

`for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)`